# Node.js v8-profiler module won't install

Tags: memory, node.js, module, memory-leaks, npm

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in a Node.js application but cannot install the v8-profiler module via npm:

```
npm install v8-profiler
```

The response (shortened to the error section) - you can see the full error and more comments about it here: https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler/issues/9

```
Build failed:
 -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cxx snapshot.cc -> snapshot_1.o}
 -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cxx graph_path.cc -> graph_path_1.o}
 -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cxx graph_node.cc -> graph_node_1.o}
npm ERR! error installing v8-profiler@0.0.3
```

I am using node 0.6.10 built from source on Debian 6.0.3. I've not had any issues with any other NPM modules.

I also tried an install of the module on a machine with the same OS but using node 0.4.12 with the same issue.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's failing to compile. Maybe it doesn't like your cxx compiler. What compiler and version of it are you using?

Comment: So it looks like the v8-profiler has now been updated to support node 0.6.10. I'll be checking out the latest build to see if it works.

Comment: What OS are you using? Make sure you're using the V8 that is installed with Node and not a V8 you already may have installed.

Comment: Hey, as stated I'm running Debian 6.0.3. V8 is Node's install not a custom one.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I commented right before I fell asleep. I've heard other's having similar problems and I know that this is something the Node team has been working on (profiling a node app). Does this article help: https://plus.google.com/u/0/116160612483689327039/posts/1dAUHMUNE29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The v8-profiler wouldn't compile with the latest version of Node.js but has now been updated fixing the issues above. Problem solved.